# installing kali linuc 2.0 on two hard drives?

Tags: multi-boot, kali-linux

Hello I was wondering if it was possible to install kali 2.0 on a second hard drive connected to my laptop? My first hard drive isn't big enough to hold both or I would do that but the second has 1tb. 500gb which is unused. I am using an ASUS G751j the only other option I have is VM or live usb with persistence.

Comment: Try pointing the kali installer at the 2nd HD? And can your computer boot from the 2nd drive, with a boot menu or setting?

Comment: Not sure. Ill have to look at it. I have tried to install it on 20gb on the first hard drive but install system fail every time. Yes I ran a checksum and looked up other stuff to figure it out nut to no end.

Comment: 20GB  should be enough. The problem is not space, it must be something else. What makes you think that you are not going to find the same problem when you install on the larger drive?

Comment: I dont think that. Ive tried mutiple ways of installing it without success. I just tried to install it on the second hard drive and the system froze. I have also tried vm and messing with the settings. The only thing that i have ever gotten it pass the install stage was when i deleted all the old vm files from previous installs and tried from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted the parttion to fat 32 and then tried installing with text based installer. Worked the first time. Must have been the way the parttion was formatted.